# div con posicion absoluta no respeta posicion relativa de su contenedor

Tags: css, html5

tengo una problema para diseñar las pestañas del Section en el Home de una Web que estoy desarrollando.

Pese a que tengo establecido el contenedor con posición relativa, las cajas con posición absoluta siguen tomando como referencia el ancho y alto de la propia página, pero no el de su contenedor.

Paso captura y fragmento del código. Seguro es una tontería, pero no logro dar con la solución.

--CÓDIGO--
/*He probado a dejar como posición relative únicamente el contenedor de las cajas que se posicionan absolute, y también (como muestra el siguiente código) dejando los contenedores padre como relative, pero sin ningún resultado.*/

A continuación se detalla el código del archivo .CSS

```
/*SECTION*/

/*Este bloque es el contenedor del propio section de la página (a section no le he definido ningún estilo css)*/

.contenedorSection{

    width: 90%; height: 880px;
    position: relative;

    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;

    border: 2px solid black;
}

/*Este bloque es el contenedor de los div que sirven como pestañas del Section*/
.contPestanasSect{

    width: 100%; height: 880px;
    **position: relative;**
}

/*Esta clase define a las pestañas del section, que son también div que continen etiqueta p*/

.pestSect{

    width: 200px; height: 100px;
    **position: absolute;**

    /*define la posicion del texto*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    /*define el borde*/
    border: 2px solid #1CD7DF;

}

/*los id que determinan la posición de cada pestaña dentro del section (en el caso de #a lo he dejado al 100% para que se vea claramente que sobrepasa el borde de su contenedor*/

#a{

    top: 40%; left: 100%;
}

#b{

    top: 60%; left: 65%;
}

#c{

    top: 40%; left: 45%;
}

#d{

    width: 240px;
    top: 60%; left: 25%;
}

#e{

    top: 40%; left: 5%;
}
```

A Continuación paso la estructura del archivo HTML

```
<!--BLOQUE SECTION-->

        <div class="contenedorSection">

              <section>

                  <div class="contPestanasSect">
                      <div class="pestSect" id="a"><p class="fuenteSection">ANALISIS</p></div>
                      <div class="pestSect" id="b"><p class="fuenteSection">NONSTOP</p></div>  
                      <div class="pestSect" id="c"><p class="fuenteSection">PAJAS MENTALES</p></div>
                      <div class="pestSect" id="d"><p class="fuenteSection">MISCELANEAS</p></div>
                      <div class="pestSect" id="e"><p class="fuenteSection">CANDY-SHOP</p></div> 
                  </div>

              </section>
        </div>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme. Un saludo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Pepin, bienvenido! Lo ideal es que compartas el código completo para poder ayudarte, además, si estas realmente interesado en solucionar tu problema deberías subir tu código a un sitio como https://codepen.io/pen/ de esta manera tu problema podrá ser solucionado lo más pronto posible.

Comment: Hola, he subido el código completo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te felicito por intentar resolverlo por ti mismo. Eh encontrado la razón de tu problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando tu aplicas left:100% haces que el elemeto tenga un espacio a la izquierda del 100%, lo cual, por supuesto causa un desbordamiento.

Para lograr el resultado que esperas, puedes hacer uso de flexbox (https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Edité algunas cosas de tu css y quedo así:

```
/*SECTION*/


/*HACE QUE EL TEXTO NO SE SALGA DE SU CONTENEDOR*/
p{
  word-break: break-all;
  hyphens: auto;
  text-align:center;
-ms-word-break: break-all;
-webkit-hyphens: auto;
-moz-hyphens: auto;
-ms-hyphens: auto;
word-break: break-word;
} */


.contenedorSection{

    width: 90%; height: 880px;
    position: relative;

    margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;

    border: 2px solid black;
}

/*Este bloque es el contenedor de los div que sirven como pestañas del Section*/
.contPestanasSect{

    width: 100%; height: 880px;
    position: relative;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
/*   overflow:hidden; */
}

/*Esta clase define a las pestañas del section, que son también div que continen etiqueta p*/

.pestSect{

    width: 15%;
  height: 100px;


    /*define la posicion del texto*/
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;

    /*define el borde*/
    border: 2px solid #1CD7DF;

}

/*los id que determinan la posición de cada pestaña dentro del section (en el caso de #a lo he dejado al 100% para que se vea claramente que sobrepasa el borde de su contenedor*/

#a{


  margin-top:50%;
}

#b{


}

#c{

  margin-top:50%;
}

#d{



}

#e{

    margin-top:50%;
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado. No olvides marcar la respuesta que mejor te ayude como válida para ayudar a otras personas con tu mismo problema en el futuro. Suerte!

Comment: Sé que no recomiendan aportar como comentarios los agradecimientos. Aún así, muchas gracias Joel Muñoz. Tu respuesta me ha ayudado enormemente. Había utilizado con éxito el flex-box en el nav del header, pero no logré hacerlo para el section. Mi visión realmente era la de no usar flex-box en el section, que los div no modificaran su tamaño en base a la dimensión de pantalla, sino que apareciera la barra de desplazamiento cuando ésta fuera más pequeña, no sé si me explico. Un saludo, y nuevamente gracias =)

Answer (score 0):

tu codigo no esta mal, para obtener lo que queres tenes que fijarte bien en las medidas que le pusiste a los  div con clase "pestSect"

```
#a{

    top: 40%; left: 100%;  //le sumas 35% , aca tendrias que poner 85% y funciona
}

#b{

    top: 60%; left: 65%;   //le sumas 20%
}

#c{

    top: 40%; left: 45%;  // le sumas 20%
}

#d{

    width: 240px;
    top: 60%; left: 25%; // le sumas 20%
}

#e{

    top: 40%; left: 5%; //empezas con 5%
}
```

provando a meter un left de 0% a la e, se ve como el absolute respeta el relative del contenedor, modifica el left del id "a" y ponelo en 85% y obtenes lo que estas buscando ☺
espero que sea de ayuda

Comment: El caso es que lo tenía al 85%, pero al disminuir la ventana en el navegador (bajar la resolución), sobresale igualmente del borde de su contenedor. En principio, al poner 100%, debería situarse en el borde del contenedor, pero no sobrepasarlo. Gracias igualmente por tu comentario =)

Comment: @pepinS podes probar a cambiar el width del pestSect y ponerlo asi : 12vw
esto te ayuda a que la dimencion sea proporcional a la anchura del browser